# Techniques to use to check if iOS standalone App trial period has expired?

Tags: ios, iphone

We allow users to use our iOS stand alone App for a trial period of 1 month. After the trial period, the app should prompt the user to  purchase.

Comment: This may violate section 2.9 of the approval guidelines https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality

Answer (score 0):

you could store the date when the app is first launched in NSUserDefaults. That means though that the user can delete the app and install it again to use the trail period again and again. if you want to prevent that you have to handle that in your backend database...

code sample:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let firstLaunchDate = userDefaults.objectForKey("firstLaunchDate") as? NSDate {
      print(firstLaunchDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)
      // 1 month = ~30 days * 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 secons = 2.592.000 seconds
      if abs(firstLaunchDate.timeIntervalSinceNow) > 2_592_000 {
        // prompt the user to purchase
      }
    } else {
      let firstLaunchDate = NSDate()
      userDefaults.setObject(firstLaunchDate, forKey: "firstLaunchDate")
      userDefaults.synchronize()
    }

    return true
  }
```

Comment: Keychain is a better choice than NSUserDefaults

Comment: Because it is encrypted and can't simply be edited like NSUserDefaults and will persist across an app delete/reinstall

Comment: i think the first launch date isn't something that needs to be encrypted. and if you really want to prevent manipulation and make sure that the user uses a trial period just once you should definitely handle that in your backend!